# how to fix my Dockerfile to generate a successful image?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

i have some troubles trying to Dockerize an asp.net Core API, and the Dockerfile's build fails when I try to use a directory that is in my server

Thanks in advance

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY netuse\\000.000.00.000/NugetRepository$/nugetproy/MongoRefMapValidator/ /src
COPY netuse\\000.000.00.000/NugetRepository$/nugetproy/CanonicalModels/ /src
COPY netuse\\000.000.00.000/NugetRepository$/nugetproy/CanonicalConstants/ /src
CMD xcopy C:/proy/proyCore/.nuget/nuget.config /root/.nuget/NuGet/
COPY ./MyESAPI.csproj src/
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyESAPI
RUN dotnet build "MyESAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyESAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myesapi.dll"]
```

in"000.000.00.000" is the ip address of my server
this is my error:

```
COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder520676771\netuse\000.000.00.000\NugetRepository$\nugetproy\MongoRefMapValidator: El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
```

Comment: Is there a typo?  Is it supposed to be `nugetproxy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're building an image outside the Docker context: it means the `Dockerfile` should live in the upper folder containing your source files, something like this:

```
my_project
├── src/
│   ├── my_file.ext
│   └── another_file.ext
└── Dockerfile
```

This means the Docker daemon can push on the image layer *just* files inside the context that is `my_project`: in fact, from the snippet you shared, you're trying to copy stuff from a network share (I guess due to `netuse` path).